# How to find a key-value pair in json text using shell scripting with in-built linux tools like sed?

Tags: json, shell, sed, sh

I have a JSON file `abc.json` containing text:

```
{
    "size": 3,
    "limit": 25,
    "isLastPage": true,
    "values": [

        {
            "slug": "docker_apache_customised",
            "id": 234889,
            "name": "docker_apache_customised",
            "scmId": "git",
            "state": "AVAILABLE",
            "statusMessage": "Available",
            "forkable": true,
            "project": {
                "key": "UFD",
                "id": 36239,
                "name": "UF_docker",
                "public": false,
                "type": "NORMAL",
                "links": {
                    "self": [{
                        "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/projects/UFD"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "public": false,
            "links": {
                "clone": [{
                    "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/scm/ufd/docker_apache_customised.git",
                    "name": "http"
                }, {
                    "href": "ssh://git@git.rnd.xxx.net/ufd/docker_apache_customised.git",
                    "name": "ssh"
                }],
                "self": [{
                    "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/projects/UFD/repos/docker_apache_customised/browse"
                }]
            }
        },

        {
            "slug": "web-software",
            "id": 241533,
            "name": "web-software",
            "scmId": "git",
            "state": "AVAILABLE",
            "statusMessage": "Available",
            "forkable": true,
            "project": {
                "key": "UFD",
                "id": 36239,
                "name": "UF_docker",
                "public": false,
                "type": "NORMAL",
                "links": {
                    "self": [{
                        "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/projects/UFD"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "public": false,
            "links": {
                "clone": [{
                    "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/scm/ufd/web-software.git",
                    "name": "http"
                }, {
                    "href": "ssh://git@git.rnd.xxx.net/ufd/web-software.git",
                    "name": "ssh"
                }],
                "self": [{
                    "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/projects/UFD/repos/web-software/browse"
                }]
            }
        },

        {
            "slug": "web-loy-conf",
            "id": 240959,
            "name": "web-loy-conf",
            "scmId": "git",
            "state": "AVAILABLE",
            "statusMessage": "Available",
            "forkable": true,
            "project": {
                "key": "UFD",
                "id": 36239,
                "name": "UF_docker",
                "public": false,
                "type": "NORMAL",
                "links": {
                    "self": [{
                        "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/projects/UFD"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "public": false,
            "links": {
                "clone": [{
                    "href": "ssh://git@git.rnd.xxx.net/ufd/web-loy-conf.git",
                    "name": "ssh"
                }, {
                    "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/scm/ufd/web-loy-conf.git",
                    "name": "http"
                }],
                "self": [{
                    "href": "https://rndwww.abc.xxx.net/git/projects/UFD/repos/web-loy-conf/browse"
                }]
            }
        }
    ],
    "start": 0
}
```

This text contains three repositories(named `docker_apache_customised`, `web-software`, `web-loy-conf`) in a `git` project. There may be more repos containing `web` as substring.

I want to perform some operation on the repositories which has `web` as substring, and for that I think I have to apply a for loop in shell script. I don't want to use `jq` tool

I wrote a script using external tool `jq`, but I want to do it with Linux in-built tools only. The script using `jq` is working fine:

```
for k in $(jq '.values | keys | .[]' abc.json); do

    value=$(jq -r ".values[$k]" abc.json);
    name=$(jq -r '.name' <<< "$value");

    if [[ $name == *"web"* ]]; then

        #MYLOGIC
    done
done
```

Expected result are names (`web-software`, `web-loy-conf`) and to be able to loop through that

Comment: You need to state why you can't use `jq`, any system limitation or other? Because that is right tool for the job

Comment: Actually, the actual scenario is, I am running a build script (which will be triggeres through software factory) which needs jq to be installed, and it should be accessible to the build.sh script
Now I have installed jq in my PC from http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/linux64/jq and moved it in a git repo. Now, in my bash script I am cloning this git repo which contains 'jq' (downloaded from internet) and from there I am running this command 'chmod +x jq && sudo cp jq /usr/local/bin'. And becaue I don't have admin privileges, I am not able to add jq in /usr/local/bin

Comment: If I run 'sudo yum install jq' directly from shell, I am getting error : sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: jq is the right tool  for the job. inbuilt tools are not made for handling JSON data and rather generic data processing. any nested json will fail with inbuilt tools

Answer (score 0):

You can run `jq` from its current path in your git repository, there's no need to copy it to a directory in the PATH. After adding execution permissions:

```
value=$(<path to jq in git dir>/jq -r ".values[$k]" abc.json);
```

You can make it relative to git repository root

```
value=$(./<path to jq from git repo root>/jq -r ".values[$k]" abc.json);
```

Also, you can set the path to it in a variable

```
jqbin='./<path to jq from git repo root>/jq'
value=$($jqbin -r ".values[$k]" abc.json);
```